# How to add new element to the end of array in Java

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

```
StudentModel[] student = new StudentModel[] {
     new StudentModel(1, "Kanha", "Vong", "Female", "09/09/2000", "Siem Reap", "016663332"),
     new StudentModel(2, "Echrysa", "Chhy", "Male", "01/20/2000", "Pursat", "097222444"),
     new StudentModel(3, "Sopheak", "Chok", "female", "29/06/2005", "Battambang", "096565544"),
     new StudentModel(4, "Sakda", "Heang", "Male", "04/12/2001", "Banteay Meanchey", "097889900"),
     new StudentModel(5, "TongHan", "Khy", "Male", "03/06/2002", "Pursat", "0976543201"),
     new StudentModel(6, "Seyma", "Hor", "Female", "27/08/2004", "Battambang", "015765456")
};

public void insertStudent(StudentModel[] student){
    int n = student.length;
    student = new StudentModel[n+1];

    System.out.print("Enter Student ID:");
    student[n].setId(sc.nextInt());

    System.out.print("Enter First Name:");
    student[n].setFirstName(sc.nextLine());

    .......................................


}
```

I've got error message: Cannot invoke "StudentModel.setId(int)"
because "student[n]" is null. Anyone can help to fix this? Thank you!

Comment: Method parameter `student` has the same name as class field `student` (the field is populated with data), so it is the one used in the method. All array elements are initialized as `null`, so you don't have data to work with. Initialize the element at the index you want to work with.

Comment: I've to try rename method parameter but not work.

Answer (score 0):

Are you depended on Arrays?

If not you could use Map with List or two Lists. My guess:

```
privat Map<int,List<String>> students = new HashMap<int, List<String>>();

public void addStudent(int id,String name, String lastName, String birthdate,...){
   List<String> student = new LinkedList<String>(); //LinkedList for fixed order
   student.add(name);
   student.add(lastName);
   student.add(birthdate);

   students.put(id, student);
}
```

Should work like this and with LinkedList the order is fixed and you can get the data by knowing the index if needed

Otherwise you could try a List in a List.

Advantage here ist that you can easy access the data of the students by index and good methods!

Comment: Of course, List is easy but i want to use array. I am practice how to use object of array.

Comment: Than you could try adding something by creating a temporary Array with one more slot, loop through the old one and add the already existing data inside the new one. Than add the new Line you wanted to append and finish it by assigning the temporary array to students

Comment: I did it, but isn't working. 
StudentModel[] tempStudent = new StudentModel[student.length+1];
        for (int i = 0; i < student.length; i++) {
            tempStudent[i].setId(student[i].getId());
            tempStudent[i].setFirstName(student[i].getFirstName());
            tempStudent[i].setLastName(student[i].getLastName());
            ........................................................................................
        }

I've got error message: Cannot invoke "StudentModel.setId(int)" because "tempStudent[i]" is null

Comment: Yeah cause you try to access something what doesnt exist. You have to set Objects inside the temp and not single parameter. With temp we create an empty array with an bigger size and you have to fill it up with the already given Objects you have from your old array and after that with the new Object

Comment: Finally, I did it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try this

```
        String[] test = new String[]{"Test1", "Test2"};
        
        //try new on
        String[] tester = new String[test.length + 1];
        for(int i = 0; i < test.length; i++){
            tester[i] = test[i];
        }
        
        // -1 cause of index 0 to length - 1
        tester[tester.length - 1] = "Test3";
        
        test = tester;
        
        for(String text : test){
            System.out.println(text);
        }
```

worked fine for me

Comment: Replace String[] to StudentModel[] is not working. I wanna use StudentModel[] not String[].

Comment: I tried it by creating an own StudentModel class with nearly same propertys and it worked on the same way as in the code above. There should be no difference between String and StudentModel because they both are Objects